# Why is auto formatting "not available" for cshtml in my Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, razor, autoformatting

While searching for an answer to this I've seen enough posts on here about the issues with the auto formatter to know that auto format should be possible. However, when I ctrl-k+ctrl-d I get:

> "The key combination (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D) is bound to command (Format
>   Document) which is not currently available."

Any idea what gives? I just reset my settings to use C# settings (they were set to Web Development prior) but that didn't do anything.

Comment: Upon closer inspection it appears the version of VS doesn't really recognize the cshtml extension at all so I'm guessing it's a version that hasn't been updated. That's what I'm looking in to now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that the computer I was using had not been updated to .NET 4.0 - updating the framework resolved the issue. I was thrown off a bit because the project would still build and run fine.